# FreeBSD portupgrade error: Packages are not yet suported

Tags: freebsd, packages

I'm trying to update one of packages that I installed earlier but I'm running into this error:

```
# portupgrade -PP wget
USING PKGNG
Packages are not yet suported. Use pkg(8) directly.

# uname -a
FreeBSD f9.alexus.org 9.1-RELEASE-p5 FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE-p5 #0: Sat Jul 27 01:14:23 UTC 2013     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

# portupgrade --help
....
-p, --package            Build package when each port is installed
-P, --use-packages       Use packages instead of ports whenever available;
                         Specified twice, --use-packages-only is implied
    --use-packages-only  Or -PP; Use no ports but packages only
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. How can I have portupgrade to *NOT* switch to `pkgng/pkg(8)`?

Answer (score 3):

I would think the error message is pretty self explanatory:

> `Packages are not yet suported.`

. . . therefore you must . . .

> `Use pkg(8) directly.`

or alternatively don't specify `-PP` and upgrade `wget` via the port instead of trying to use the package...

Comment: sorry, not so clear to me. I _DO_ want to use packages (over /usr/ports) and I'm looking for a way to update them, after some Google-ing this subject i found to use portupgrade -PP or portmaster.

Comment: @alexus The error message is telling you "This tool doesn't do that (yet)".

Comment: portupgrade is switching to pkgng, and pkg(8) suggests that feature isn't supported, yet portupgrade itself works w/ packages (see output)